# How is the Precision edge shared?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, ranger, animal-companions

A few ranger feats share the hunter's edge benefits, namely [Animal Companion](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=311) and [Warden's Boon](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=518) (and the feats that require it):

> Ranger: When you Hunt Prey, your animal companion gains the action's benefits and your hunter's edge benefit if you have one.

> By pointing out vulnerabilities, you grant the benefits listed in Hunt Prey and your hunter’s edge benefit to an ally until the end of their next turn. Depending on whether you call out or use gestures, this action gains either the auditory or visual trait.

However, it's  unclear to me how this should play out for the [Precision](https://2e.aonprd.com/HuntersEdge.aspx?ID=2) edge:

> You have trained to aim for your prey’s weak points. The first time you hit your hunted prey in a round, you also deal 1d8 additional precision damage.

**Is there 1d8 per round per beneficiary** (ranger, animal companion, warden's boon ally, etc.)**?**
This was my first reading, but then I became concerned that this could skirt into 'too good to be true' territory. (For a while I was especially concerned about sharing the Masterful Hunter Upgrade in this way with, say, a fighter; later it became clear that this is impossible because there is no equivalent to [Masterful Companion](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=543) in the Warden's Boon feat line)

**Or is there 1d8 per round, used by whichever beneficiary hits first?**
Compared to a lone ranger, it's less likely that every beneficiaries misses all their strikes thereby wasting the 1d8.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Precision is applied once per beneficiary

The Warden feats grant

> the benefits listed in Hunt Prey and your hunter’s edge benefit

to others. The benefit of the Precision Edge is

> The first time **you** hit your hunted prey in a round, you also deal 1d8 additional precision damage.

Each target has this benefit, for themselves to deal bonus damage. I would *assume* (because it's required for the ability to do anything) that the Ranger's Hunted Prey benefits 'count as' "your hunted prey" for the purposes of the granted Edge.

To look at it another way, each target is guided to hit with Precision... another person doing so does not affect your ability to hit the point you're trying to.

As for it being "too good"... the damage is significant but not absurd, requires heavy Feat investment, a pretty high level (especially the higher Warden Feats that allow you to designate more than one beneficiary), Actions to enact, (enough) allies that can successfully benefit from the ability, and for your allies to focus on targets of your choice.